# How to recover deleted SQLite database files?

Tags: data-recovery, sqlite

How to recover deleted SQLite database files?

Using `magicrescue` tool with the following params simply extracts the SQL query files instead:

```
sudo magicrescue -r sqlite -d ~/output /dev/hdb1
```

Comment: /Restore from backup ?

Comment: It's difficult to recover files on Linux filesystems. You can use tools such as the ones detailed in three following tutorial. Hope this introduces you to forensics and helps you to recover them.

Comment: Just restore the files from your backup, It's much easier than messing around with recovery programs. You also risk that the files recovered is not complete because of the way the file system release and reuse disk space when deleting and adding / expanding files. If you haven't unmounted the FS, or at least remounted it ReadOnly immediately when the files where deleted, it's almost sure that some of the data has been overwritten already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that `magicrescue` creates the SQL file from found database file really.

The `/usr/share/magicrescue/recipes/sqlite` is a special recipe which achieves this:

```
# Extracts sqlite databases
# Author: Eric Pozharski <whynot@pozharski.name>
# See #730007
#
0 string SQLite format 3\x00
extension sqlite

# Result will be "CREATE TABLE"'s and "INSERT INTO"'s
allow_overlap -1
#min_output_file 1024
command dd bs=1M count=16 of="$1.with-trash" 2>/dev/null; sqlite3 -init /dev/null "$1.with-trash" .dump >"$1" ; rm -f "$1.with-trash"
```

So resulted `*.sqlite` files are really SQL files created from found database files.